# Cannot resolve symbols for Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I installed Vaadin on IntelliJ, using the trial mode of 14 days. I created a Vaadin 8 design including several UI components, yet they cannot be resolved. In particular, for these lines of code

```
import com.vaadin.annotations.AutoGenerated;
import com.vaadin.annotations.DesignRoot;
import com.vaadin.ui.declarative.Design;
import com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent;
```

I get the messages 'Cannot resolve symbol ui' and 'Cannot resolve symbol annotations'. The lines were automatically generated after I created the .html file of the design, along with the lines

```
@DesignRoot
@AutoGenerated
```

in my code. That means I have a vaadin package than can be located, yet it doesn't include the annotations and the ui components. What am I supposed to do?

Thank you in advance

PS: I am using Fedora, if it plays any role

Comment: I think vaadin plugin just helps you to develop faster, but if you want to run your code those dependencies must be included in your pom.xml. Did you tried adding those to you pom.xml

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to use a Vaadin 8 design in a project that uses Vaadin 10 or newer? Those are not compatible.